# Anquilla Framework - Multiple select control

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I'm making a simple GUI extension and I can't find an example of an SDL Tridion multiple select.

I could use my own html version for example:

```
<select multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

But I'd like to stick the ones SDL uses for their own GUI elements so I can use some of the functions / actions that come with it (mainly supplying an XML list of items).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the Page Publisher, which uses multiselect for TargetTypes. It will be

`<c:List id="TargetTypeList" runat="server" TabIndex="1" MultiSelect="true" />`

Powertools link for page publisher : https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FPowerTools.Editor%2FPowerTools%2FClient%2FPagePublisher

Comment: Considering the author of that extension, I'm glad he shared it with the community to help the author of this question.`</Open source and PowerTools plug>` ;-)